# Change 8-connectivity of pixels in an image to 4-connectivity

Tags: matlab, image-processing, vision, image-morphology

I have a BW image containing a  [8-Connected path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3ljL.png)

The image needs to be changed such that there is a 4-connectivity between the pixels, i.e. one can traverse the whole path without going diagonally.

This process needs to be done using morphological operations.

One possible output is this image. [4-Connected path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF98H.png)

Comment: Erode it with an specific erosion kernel (`strel`)

Comment: Can you suggest any kernel for this specific case? Path consists of black pixels, which needs to be 4-connected.

Comment: What would the expected result be?

Comment: Expected result now attached in the main question text.

Comment: Is each square a pixel, or is each square composed of several pixels?  Is this the true image that you have uploaded?

Comment: Yes each square is a single pixel.

Comment: Is there some other constraint you haven't mentioned? Else my solution might be to make them all black...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit-or-miss operations are part of mathematical morphology, so I would do the opposite of a skeletonize operation.

So I would use this hit-or-miss filter:

> X 0 1
>
> X 1 0
>
> X X X

X being any values. With such a mask, you connect black pixels (value 0) that touch each others by a corner
Don't forget to build the three other rotations (90°, 180° and 270°) of the filter.

Here is the pseudocode:

```
Input: Input Image In, Output Image Out, the four hit-or-miss filters F0, F1, F2, F3
Copy In into Out
For each pixel p in In
    if F0 is true for p, or F1 is true for p, F2 is true for p, F3 is true for p
        Out(p) becomes black.
```

Comment: How will I then combine these 4 hit-miss filtered images together to get the desired result? Can you explain the whole process because I'm unable to fully understand your point.

Comment: I think two of the structuring elements are sufficient unless planning to do this inplace.

Comment: I think that we miss some cases if we don't use 4 SE.

Comment: Because they are corner connected, I'd like to speak of 45, 225, 135, 315 /deg rotations. Frankly, they are pairwise the same just detecting a corner connection (=line) from opposite sides. So you actually make the line too thick by using them all. Using upper or lower set changes the result a bit, obviously.

Comment: Indeed, the line is going to be a little bit thicker.